# Why is pyspark taking so long to read CSV files from a directory on my Windows 11 machine?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to grab all CSV files from a directory with pyspark, but am running into huge performance issues. I expect it to run quickly as it is all running locally on my machine (Windows 11) and the directory has 2 matching CSV files, each with 20 rows.

First, I initialize spark with:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Then, to get all the files in my directory (`C:\temp2\temp3\`), I use:

```py
path = r'C:\temp2\temp3\*.csv'
df2 = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(path)

df2.show()
```

However, I have waited for this command to finish for 10+ minutes, and it fails to complete each time.

Interestingly, when trying to stop the code block in VS Code, it fails to interrupt the kernel successfully and has to stop the entire process.

For my path, I have tried reading just one file and it works great:

```py
path = r'C:\temp2\temp3\Book2.csv'
```

As [per the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html), I should be able to pass the directory in as well:

```py
path = r'C:\temp2\temp3\'
```

This also fails, with or without the trailing backslash.

What is causing the performance issues, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** I have run the same exact code in a [pyspark docker container](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/main/pyspark-notebook) without issue. It appears to be an environment issue related to Windows 11.

Comment: Do the files have different schema? also any error or warning you see in the logs?

Comment: @IslamElbanna The files are carbon copies of one another. No errors or warnings from what I can see, but there may be other log locations I'm not looking.